# Как на golang узнать загруженность процессора, имя компьютера и имя пользователя на компьютере?

Tags: golang

Как на golang узнать загруженность процессора, имя компьютера и имя пользователя на компьютере?

Comment: os/user ответит как минимум на два последних вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**На stackoverflow принято не смешивать много вопросов в один.**

#### 1. Имя текущего пользователя

Пакет [`os/user`](https://godoc.org/os/user). Пример:

```
package main

import (
    "os/user"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    // текущий пользователь
    cur, err := user.Current()
    if  err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Current user:", cur)
}
```

Есть ещё выбор пользователя по имени и по идентификатору. На *play.golang.org* не работает.

#### 2. Имя компьютера.

Функция [`os.Hostname`](https://godoc.org/os#Hostname). [Play](https://play.golang.org/p/2JuesNtAXz)

#### 3. Загруженность процессора.

Использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: @"Ivan Black" Спасибо. А какие сторонние библиотеки и как их подключать? не подскажите?

Comment: Я как раз ещё здесь нашёл https://www.socketloop.com/references/golang-os-user-user-type-current-lookup-and-lookupid-functions-example

Comment: @RakzinRoman, я вот эту использовал [gosigar](https://github.com/elastic/gosigar). Но на `github` не стабильная ветка. Однако можно использовать папку `vendor` если go1.5+. Или `godep` для более старых версий.

Comment: @RakzinRoman, вот пример использования из [topbeat](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/topbeat/system/cpu.go). Но, мне она нужна была для Linux

Comment: Использовать сторонние библиотеки -- не нужно.
В том же os есть функция GetPid()int, на основе можно создать экземпляр типа os.ProcessState. У этого типа есть две функции для получения времени работы процесса:
SystemTime()
UserTime()

Comment: @prospero78su, так их можно получить только после того как процесс завершиться. Т.е. делать wait и так далее. Это приём для процессов запущенных с помощью `StartProcess` или `os/exec`.

Comment: Где в вопросе было уточнение "Узнать ВО ВРЕМЯ работы"? По-крайней мере, эта библиотека на githube ищется на раз.
github.com/shirou/gopsutil/process -- на здоровье.

Comment: @prospero78su, загруженность процессора, а не процесса. Это если говорить про вопрос.