# Как получить информацию о компьютере в golang?

Tags: golang, ос

Как получить информацию об операционной системе, устройствах, свободном месте на диске и др?

Comment: Посмотрите тут -- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/530473/232 (вообще же, судя по количеству вопросов (и особенно ответов на них), кажется go не слишком у нас популярен...)

Comment: Можно узнать какая практическая необходимость в этом?

Comment: @avp тут иногда отвечает человек, у которого золото по golang  на английском SO, а так да ... вопросов мало. Спрос, как говорится, рождает предложение, а спроса - нет.

Answer (score 4):

В стандартной библиотеке такой возможности нет, кроме [os/user](https://golang.org/pkg/os/user/) - позволяет узнать информацию о пользователе.

Для получения расширенной информации - придется использовать [os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) для вызова системных комманд (`df`, `lspci`, `free`).

Так-же что-то можно получить из пакета [syscall](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/). Пример можно подсмотреть [тут](https://gist.github.com/lunny/9828326).